# stopPropagation on select from AntDesign

Tags: javascript

I have the next application: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-snow-kjyqv?file=/index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}
function click() {
  console.log("click");
}
function onMouseEnter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <div className="click" onClick={click}>
      <Select
        onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
        defaultValue="lucy"
        style={{ width: 120 }}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  </>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

I want, when user clicks on red area to appear in console the word `click`, but when user will click on select to open it, the:

```css
function click() {
  console.log("click");
}
```

shouldn't work, this is why i inserted:

```css
function onMouseEnter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

..but anyway the stopPropagation does not work and when i clicks on select the above function also work.

Question: How to create the next scenario?: -- when user clic kson red area to apply `console.log('work')`, but when will click on select the console.log should not be visible.

Comment: can we bring <select> elements at same level as <div> , and make its position absolute providing a parent div as relative, so that styling can be proper. It mitigates that issue.
Or create a <select> element as different component which will manage its events internally can be another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stopPropogation won't stop default behavior, you need preventDefault. You should use onClick event instead of mouseEnter.

```
function onMouseEnter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

<Select
 onClick={onMouseEnter}
 defaultValue="lucy"
 style={{ width: 120 }}
 onChange={handleChange}
>
```

Comment: i apply your code, but it does not work. Do you have another solution?

Comment: could you take a look, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345237/save-data-in-a-special-order-when-click-on-button

Answer (score 1):

you need to stopPropagation in selection part in click event not in mouseEnter

i do some changes here :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}
function click() {
  console.log("click");
}
// function for stoping propagation in clikc
function onClickStopProg(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <div className="click" onClick={click}>
      <Select
      // calling function in onclick event
      // for stoping propagation 
        onClick={onClickStopProg}
        defaultValue="lucy"
        style={{ width: 120 }}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  </>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```